# Image size of ShinySky BusyIndicator

Tags: r, shiny, shinysky

I am looking for some way on how can I control the Image size in the Busy Indicator from ShinySky package. As per the help page, busyIndicator takes below inputs :

```
busyIndicator(text = "Calculation in progress..",
       img = "shinysky/busyIndicator/ajaxloaderq.gif", wait = 1000)
```

Any idea how can I control the Image size of 'img' parameter?

Thanks,